# How to retrieve the Stripe subscription id from the create subscription API call in javascript

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

A similar question has been asked before, but didn't answer the question directly. With Stripe's create subscription call:

```
stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: "cus_FrggXOPDIf2ldT",
  items: [
    {
       plan: "plan_FrbdKwJE959Ivb",
    },
  ]
}, function(err, subscription) {
     // asynchronously called
   }
);
```

There is a subscription object that is returned. Is this object returned in the callback function that is returned asynchronously? I've tried the following without success:

```
stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: "cus_FrggXOPDIf2ldT",
  items: [
    {
       plan: "plan_FrbdKwJE959Ivb",
    },
  ]
}, function(err, subscription) {
     console.log(subscription.id);
   }
);
```

How is the id returned, and how to grab it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I should have known the create subscription call returned a promise. So in that case:

```
stripe.subscriptions.create(
   {
     customer: id,
     items: [
       {
         plan: 'plan_FrbdKwJE959Aws',
       },
     ],
   },
 ).then(subscription => console.log(subscription.id));
```